# System paralyzed after too many data insertion at one time

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, database-design

I developed an inventory system that is required to track each number of serial number of items when the user decided to registers an item.

The system will generate serial numbers based on given initial serial number and end serial number that is seen on the box. So let say a box of item has 1000 item and each of the items has its own serial number beginning with initial serial number 1. Based on the context the system will generate each serial number one by one eg; 1,2,3...1000 per row in db at once when user submits the form

Now, the implementation is perfectly fine when the quantity of the item are small, but it began to paralyze the system when dealing with large numbers. as large as 1 million.

Are there alternative to these problem other than storing the serial number one by one, row by row each time the users registers an item?

Please help me, anyone?

Comment: Have you considered prepared statements? Also what do you mean paralysed? Use your monitoring tools to check CPU usage, and check your db tools to try locate the bottleneck.

Comment: Im using laravel's ORM eloquent to deal with data, so I didn't utilized prepared statement. And also the server resource will skyrocketed when users inserts large quantity item that generated eg: 100000 serial numbers.

Comment: if only there are a way keep track those generated serial numbers without storing them one by one

Comment: The server was almost down, when heavy transaction happened

Answer (score 1):

You basically get the performance that you code for... For example

```
SQL> create table t ( x int );

Table created.

--
-- 100k unprepared statements, each with a commit
--
SQL>
SQL> set timing on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      execute immediate 'insert into t values ('||i||')';
  4      commit;
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:56.91

--
-- 100k prepared statements, each with a commit
--

SQL>
SQL> set timing on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      insert into t values (i);
  4      commit;
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.81

--
-- 100k prepared statements, one commit
--

SQL>
SQL> set timing on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  3      insert into t values (i);
  4    end loop;
  5    commit;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.73


--
-- 1 array-based insert prepared statements, one commit
--

SQL> set timing on
SQL> declare
  2    type numlist is table of number
  3      index by pls_integer;
  4    n numlist;
  5  begin
  6    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
  7      n(i) := i;
  8    end loop;
  9    forall i in 1 .. 100000
 10      insert into t values (n(i));
 11    commit;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
SQL>
SQL>

--
-- or we can bump those number up a bit
--
SQL> set timing on
SQL> declare
  2    type numlist is table of number
  3      index by pls_integer;
  4    n numlist;
  5  begin
  6    for i in 1 .. 10000000 loop
  7      n(i) := i;
  8    end loop;
  9    forall i in 1 .. 10000000
 10      insert into t values (n(i));
 11    commit;
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:05.15

which is around 2million rows per second (on my laptop)
```

Comment: thanks I'll try implementing this, is this the prepared statements?

Comment: I was using PLSQL for simplicity (referencing a variable is automatically prepared).  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/ullman-bindings-088836.html for a PHP example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood *how* you are doing that.

However, if you look at this Oracle demonstration (as I don't know Laravel), you'll see that inserting a *puny* 1 million rows takes no time & no (significant) resources. Hopefully, you could do something like that on your system.

```
SQL> create table serial (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_serial (par_start in number, par_end in number)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    insert into serial (id)
  5      select level + par_start - 1
  6      from dual
  7      connect by level <= par_end - par_start + 1;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set timing on
SQL> begin
  2    p_serial(1, 1000000);  -- 1 million
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.83                         --> 83 miliseconds
SQL> set timing off
SQL> select count(*), min(id) min_id, max(id) max_id from serial;

  COUNT(*)     MIN_ID     MAX_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
   1000000          1    1000000             --> 1 million values inserted

SQL>
```

Comment: what is this for real? My god! 83 miliseconds

Comment: Yes, it was for real. My suggestion is: let database do the *dirty* job, don't do it in any front-end application you wanted it to.